# STM8SF103 Assembly - Load immediate value to ram register

Tags: assembly, stm8

I am trying to write a program in assembly language for the `stm8sf103` microcontroller.
I would like to store an immediate hexadecimal value in a ram register (such as $0), but this isn't working and i am wondering why:

```
stm8/
    segment 'rom'

loop
    ld  $0,#5
    jp  loop

    end
```

I get the error:

`as1 : Error 54: Can't match Addressing mode '  ld  $0,#5'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
MOV $0, #5
```

The instruction *doesn't* affect any condition flag.

From the [ST8 Programming Manual](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/programming_manual/43/24/13/9a/89/df/45/ed/CD00161709.pdf/files/CD00161709.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00161709.pdf), the description of `MOV` is

> Moves a byte of data from a source address to a destination address. Data
>   is examined as it is moved<sup>1</sup>. The accumulator is not affected.
>
> There are 3 addressing modes for the `MOV` instruction:
>
> - An immediate byte to a direct memory location
> - A direct memory location to another direct memory location (from $00
>     to $FF)
> - A direct memory location to another direct memory location (from
>     $0000 to $FFFF)

You can refer to that manual for the supported addressing modes (20 in total), so you can understand why `ld  $0,#5` cannot work (there is no Direct with Immediate addressing).

---

<sup>1</sup> I can't understand this phrase, I believe there is a typo (it should be *Data is not examined ...*). The manual clearly states that no flag is affected.

Comment: @binaryBigInt As I said in my answer, you can look at the manual. You'll find that the ST8 don't have a mem-to-mem load (it has a mem-to-mem move though, `MOV $1, $7F0A` will do). Seriously, open that link and spend an hour reading that document, it is very well written and very easy to follow. You'll find it very useful. :)